# Set Authenticated User Globally for Testing in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 2.2 with ASP.Net Core Identity project.

I would like to set the authenticated User, with its UserId, globally for testing.

It this possible?

Comment: For unit testing, integration testing, or both?

Comment: `I would like to set the authenticated User, with its UserId, globally for testing.` make it more clear.

Comment: @ChrisPratt For both ... If possible

Comment: @TanvirArjel I would like the current authenticated User to be "Joh" with UserId = 1 when running the application in development environment

Comment: Well, it's two different procedures. For unit testing, you simply mock the `HttpContext` with a `User` principal that represents what you want to be used. This can be done in your test setup, to be applied to all tests. For integration testing, you'll need to establish your test server, and call an authentication endpoint, persisting the result (token or cookie, depending) and then apply that to further tests. That initial auth request can be part of your setup method, to make it apply to all tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Integration Test, you could progammly login the application, save the cookies and then attach the cookies for sub-requests.

Try to implement custom `WebApplicationFactory` like

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> : WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> where TEntryPoint : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {

        });
        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);
    }
    public new HttpClient CreateClient()
    {
        var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        var uri = new Uri("https://localhost:44344/Identity/Account/Login");
        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            CookieContainer = cookieContainer
        };
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
        var verificationToken = GetVerificationToken(httpClient, "https://localhost:44344/Identity/Account/Login");
        var contentToSend = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Email", "test@outlook.com"),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", "1qaz@WSX"),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("__RequestVerificationToken", verificationToken),
                        });
        var response = httpClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:44344/Identity/Account/Login", contentToSend).Result;
        var cookies = cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("https://localhost:44344/Identity/Account/Login"));
        cookieContainer.Add(cookies);
        var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
        return client;
    }
    private string GetVerificationToken(HttpClient client, string url)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        var verificationToken =response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        if (verificationToken != null && verificationToken.Length > 0)
        {
            verificationToken = verificationToken.Substring(verificationToken.IndexOf("__RequestVerificationToken"));
            verificationToken = verificationToken.Substring(verificationToken.IndexOf("value=\"") + 7);
            verificationToken = verificationToken.Substring(0, verificationToken.IndexOf("\""));
        }
        return verificationToken;
    }
}
```

And then

```cs
public class IntegrationTestWithIdentityTest : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

    public IntegrationTestWithIdentityTest(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {

        _factory = factory;
        _client = factory.CreateClient();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task IndexRendersCorrectTitle()
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44344/About");

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Assert.Contains("Send Email", responseString);
    }        

}
```

Source Code: [IntegrationTestWithIdentityTest](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/blob/master/IntegrationTest/IntegrationTestWithIdentityTest.cs).

If you want to mock a user which is not exist in the Identity Table, you need to define a new endpoint which will sign the user with

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "edward"));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "edward zhou"));
    //add your own claims from jwt token
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true });            
    return View();
}
```